# How to make Java or Java's Graphics2D use the Graphics card?

Tags: java, gpu, graphics2d

I was working on a 2D game and everything was fine until I simply added about ~100 `Rectangle2D.Double`'s to render (with 64x64 images). I was shocked to realize how slow it was for just about 100 objects. I immediately added precautions including drawing only if on screen, making sure the images didn't load every update, use double buffering, etc. I also found out using transformations like scale, translate, and rotate incredibly slow down performance, so I made all of the rectangles not use them. I have found sources that say Graphics2D does not utilize the GPU, so I looked up how to use the graphics card and ended up using `System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "True");` It sounded promising because I thought of C++ OpenGL and the incredible speed it had, but nevertheless, it did not speed up. I still think it is using the CPU.

TL;DR:
How do I utilize the graphics card for optimal performance in Java?

Comment: I think you gonna need a bigger boat for that

Comment: Make sure your images match your window’s GraphicsConfiguration.  You also may want to try using [VolatileImage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#createCompatibleVolatileImage%28int,int%29).

Comment: @VGR So would I load my images and store them as this new `VolatileImage` type? Currently I am using `BufferedImage` for it's `.getSubImage()` function. I am doing more research on it now.

Comment: Do you have any result @Joseph?